# Scrollbar not working and line divide in two part

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am create code css below.
I want to horizontal scroll but when sentence is too long it's not create scrolling but sentence break and show in next line.
In image i want aaaa.. should be printed in only one line and bbb.. in second line.but aaa... sentence come on second line without  tag.

html code & CSS code

this div tag container width is 80% of the screen.[image]

```css
code {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto; 
  font: 500 1em/1.5em 'Lucida Console', 'courier new', monospace;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;  
  border-left: 4px solid #6d7fcc;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<code> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br>
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</code>
```

Comment: Have you run your snippet?

Comment: yes in snippet it shows but actual not work

Comment: if it works here it works everywhere, if it doesn't work it is because you have other css properties that go in contrast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many try i get right answer..

**white-space:nowrap;**

This property remove white-space to add sentence to the new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using word break

```
word-break: normal;
```